# F# Bitwise operators and units of measure

Tags: .net, generics, f#, bitwise-operators, units-of-measurement

When I define a unit of measure in my code, I can use the basic arithmetic operators on values with the unit without any problems, e.g.

```ml
type [<Measure>] m

let a = 1<m>
let b = 2<m>
(* no problem *)
let result = a + b
```

However, I can't use bitwise operators:

```ml
type [<Measure>] m

let a = 1<m>
let b = 2<m>
(* error: The type 'int<m>' does not match the type 'int' *)
let result = a &&& b
```

Is there a way to make the bitwise operators compatible with units of measure?

Answer (score 3):

F# units of measure are not directly compatible with bitwise operators like &&& (bitwise AND), ||| (bitwise OR), and ^^^ (bitwise XOR). The reason for this is that units of measure are a static type-checking feature that's primarily used for safety and correctness in numerical computations, and bitwise operations are not supported out of the box for these types.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it's not supported out of the box. Is there anything better than dropping the UoM, applying the bitwise operator and restoring the UoM?

Comment: @LA.27, to be honest, I can see only that solution